# Choose indices in numpy arrays on particular dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

It is hard to find a clear title but an example will put it clearly.
For example, my inputs are:

```
c = np.full((4, 3, 2), 5)
c[:,:,1] *= 2

ix = np.random.randint(0, 2, (4, 3))
```

if `ix` is:

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

if want as a result:

```
array([[10,  5, 10],
       [ 5,  5, 10],
       [ 5,  5, 10],
       [10, 10,  5]])
```

My c array can be of arbitrary dimensions, as well a the dimension I want to sample in.

It sounds like interpolation, but I'm reluctant to construct a be array of indices each time I want to apply this. Is there a way of doing this using some kind of indexing on numpy arrays ? Or do I have to use some interpolation methods... 
Speed and memory are a concern here because I have to do this many times, and the arrays can be really large.

Thanks for any insight !

Comment: So, `c.shape[2]` is always `2`?

Comment: No, it can be an arbitrary number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the x, y indices with [`numpy.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html), and then use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
idx, idy = np.ogrid[:c.shape[0], :c.shape[1]]
c[idx, idy, ix]

#array([[10,  5, 10],
#       [ 5,  5, 10],
#       [ 5,  5, 10],
#       [10, 10,  5]])
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was wondering if I could avoid to create the grid... But i no other solution, I'll accept yours !

Comment: `ogrid` is an 'open' grid, with (4,1) and (1,3) arrays.  So there's nothing particularly expensive about them.  You just need a pair that broadcasts with your `ix`.  `np.ix_(range(4), range(3))` produces the same pair.